# IBAction connected with button but need a void

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, ibaction

I have i IBAction and it's connected with a button in .xib. But for a action o needed this code;

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category 
{
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];   
    scoreReporter.value = counter;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) 
     {
         [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(scoreReported:) withArg: NULL error: error];

         NSLog(@"Nice: %d", counter);  

     }];
}
```

Is there a way to connect my button with the void? Or something like that?

```
- (IBAction) subScore {
//data
}
```

Comment: void and IBAction are the same thing. IBAction is just a marker for the header file to tell IB that an action can be wired to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IBAction`(and `IBOutlet`) is just used to let XCode's Interface Builder(`IB`) know that there's a function exist. If you want use `void`, okay, but you'll not get the function shown in Interface Builder.

> **IBAction** is a special keyword that is used only to tell Xcode(*Interface Builder*) to treat a method as an action for target-action connections. IBAction is defined to **void**.
>
> **IBOutlet** is a special keyword that is used only to tell Xcode(*Interface Builder*) to treat the object as an outlet. It’s actually defined as nothing so it has no effect at compile time.

You can set the function(which is defined with `void`, and note `IBAction` is okay either, but needless here) to your button target like this:

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Generally, if you create your code programmatically(without using XCode's Interface Builder), you do not need `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` anymore. ;)